# no main manifest attribute in JAR when using jmx_exporter

Tags: java, prometheus, jmx

I have written a Java Producer and a Java Consumer in the Kafka123.jar file.

I want to expose the producer metrics defined in the kafkaproducer.yaml file. I am using the jmx_exporter to do so. I ran the following command.

```
java -javaagent:./jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.0.jar=2103:kafkaproducer.yml -jar Kafka123.jar
```

I am getting the following error response:

```
no main manifest attribute, in ./Kafka123.jar
```

I am new to Java, any idea what can be wrong.

Comment: What difficulty are you having using `jmx_exporter`? Or if you use Spring, then exposing the metrics to Spring Actuator?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please check (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)how to ask a good question.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have updated the description, I am having difficulties with the jmx_exporter.

Comment: I don't think your error has anything to do with the JMX exporter, and it's definitely not a Kafka issue, so removing the tag. You should see the same error when running the jar by itself, so you'll need to tell us how you've created it